# How to set spacy parameters true or false?

Tags: python, token, spacy

I only want to see words where is_alpha is true and is_stop is false and at the end i would like to store the lemma version of the word.
Thank you :)

```
import spacy
 
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")
 
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,token.shape_, token.is_alpha == True, token.is_stop == False )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension like

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")
print( [t.lemma_ for t in doc if t.is_alpha and not t.is_stop ] )
```

Output:

```
['Apple', 'look', 'buy', 'startup', 'billion']
```

Here, if the token only consists of letters and is not a stopword (`if t.is_alpha and not t.is_stop`) the token lemma is returned (`t.lemma_`).